# How can I convert a escaped unicode to regular format unicode

Tags: c#, unicode, emoji

I have this code to help parse the *unicode* for an *emoji*:

```
public string DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters(string value)
{
    return Regex.Replace(
       value,
      @"\\u(?<Value>[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})",
       m =>
         ((char)int.Parse(m.Groups["Value"].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToString();
    );
}
```

so I put my code as such

```
DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters("\uD83C\uDFCB\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D\u2642\uFE0F");
```

into `Console.WriteLine();` which gives me this emoji ‍♂️ so my question is how can I turn this

```
"\uD83C\uDFCB\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D\u2642\uFE0F"
```

into this Codepoints

```
U+1F3CB, U+1F3FF, U+200D, U+2642, U+FE0F
```

the codepoints above are from [Emojipedia.org](https://emojipedia.org/)

Comment: `@"\\u(?<Value>[a-fA-F0-9]{4})"` note `f` and `F`

Comment: Help me with this one i need help matching the emoji with this json file from here https://gist.github.com/oliveratgithub/0bf11a9aff0d6da7b46f1490f86a71eb?ref=webdesignernews.com

Comment: so i can get the name associated with that emoji i know it can be done with Json.Net but idk how to implement it

Comment: It seems you want to combine two *surrogate* characters into one Utf-32. If it's your case, please, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you want to combine *two surrogate* characters into *one* Utf-32:

```
\uD83C\uDFCB => \U0001F3CB
```

If it's your case, you can put it like this:

**Code:**

```
public static IEnumerable<int> CombineSurrogates(string value) {
  if (null == value)
    yield break; // or throw new ArgumentNullException(name(value));

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i) {
    char current = value[i];
    char next = i < value.Length - 1 ? value[i + 1] : '\0';

    if (char.IsSurrogatePair(current, next)) {
      yield return (char.ConvertToUtf32(current, next));

      i += 1;
    }
    else
      yield return (int)current;
  }
}

public static string DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters(string value) =>
  string.Join(" ", CombineSurrogates(value).Select(code => $"U+{code:X4}"));
```

**Demo:**

```
string data = "\uD83C\uDFCB\uD83C\uDFFF\u200D\u2642\uFE0F";

// If you want codes, uncomment the line below
//int[] codes = CombineSurrogates().ToArray(data);

string result = DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters(data);

Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
U+1F3CB U+1F3FF U+200D U+2642 U+FE0F
```